# how do I access specific elements in a tuple?

Tags: python-2.7, tuples

tupMonNames = ["January","Feburary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","Decmber"]

how can i display the elements that begin with 'J' using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use **startswith** built-in function for strings.

```
for item in tupMonNames:
    if item.startswith('J'):
            print item
```

Result:

```
January
June
July
```

Comment: Kavin, please mark the answer as selected if it has solved your problem...